# selenium (java) findelements in findelements

Tags: java, selenium, find, element

i want to find some elements of one class ("class1) out of many elements of class2. is there a possibility?

e.g.: findElements(By.className("class2")).findElements(By.className(class1)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this would be a CSS selector:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("class2 > class1"));
```

`By.className` accepts a single class name, as identified by the method name.